# How to display in <th>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please can someone help me with this problem?
I have game from w3schools in javascript and there is onload in body and I have a table and need put it in

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th><h4>Cookie clicker </h4></th>
                <th><h4>Sport Heads Football Championship</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Slither.io</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Game</h4></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href="http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/"><img src="pictures/cookie.jpg" alt="cookieclicker" height="450" width="450"></a>
                </th>


                <th>
                    <a href="http://www.webgames.cz/sports-heads-football-championship/4295-0/"><img src="pictures/sportheads.jpg" height="450" width="450"></a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="http://www.slither.io"><img src="pictures/slither.jpg" height="450" width="450"></a>
                </th>
                <th id="table">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

this is that table and this is

```
            <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('table');
                startGame();
            };
            </script>
```

game is in top of page no in the table. Can someone solve it please? I don't really know how to to it.
[This is the pic where is a game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Zyl.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Hard to make any sense out of this question. Not at all clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

`<th>` is the Table Header element...

Use the `<td>` element instead, it is the table cell element. (It's Table Data)

Since `<th>` is the header element, on some implementations it might ignore or override the `<tr>` element.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th).